# TypeScript: how to map interface to custom data types

Tags: typescript

I have the following types:

```
interface USER {
    email: string;
    age: number;
}
```

```
interface SCORES {
    likes: number;
    followers: number;
}
```

and then composite state as shown below:

```
interface UserStats {
    user: USER;
    stats: SCORES;
}
```

Now I get a `payload` which looks like this:

`{type: 'user', values: {email:"abc@gmail.com",age: 21}}`
or
`{type: 'stats', values: {likes:20,followers: 21}}`

While destructuring the above payload, I need to assign its type such that it covers both the cases, something like:

```
type payloadKeyTypes = 'user' | 'stats'
type configPayload = USER | SCORES
interface payloadType {
    [payloadKeyTypes]: configPayLoad
}
```

But this says: `A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type`

How do I go for resolving it?

Comment: You should use `type Record` instead of `interface`. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/wX2YVm). Btw, there is no `numeric` type - only `number`

Comment: As for using `symbols` and `template strings` as index signature in interface you can see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) and [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512)

Comment: Hey Thanks, would you mind adding it as answer so that I could accept it and close this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using union type as an index signature in interface is forbidden. However, since  [typescript 4.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) you can use symbols and template literal strings.

In this particular case, worth using [type Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) because it allows you to use unions:

```js
interface USER {
    email: string;
    age: number;
}

interface SCORES {
    likes: number;
    followers: number;
}

interface UserStats {
    user: USER;
    stats: SCORES;
}

type payloadKeyTypes = 'user' | 'stats'

type configPayload = USER | SCORES

type payloadType = Record<payloadKeyTypes, configPayload>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wX2YVm)

Also, be aware that there is a naming convention in typescript. All types/interfaces/enums should be Capitalized and CamelCased. However, it is only a convention.